# Iterate through an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

within the console.log I am receiving an array{items: Array(1)}

```
items: Array(1)
0: {id: 4, imageIndex: 3}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

I am trying to print through this array to retrieve the imageIndex and getting an undefined.

```
for (var image in imageList) {
    console.log(image.imageIndex);
}
```

If I use for...of within the loop, I get an 'imageList' is not iterable.

Comment: IF you use for in , it gives you the index, then you might have to access it as item[i].imageIndex

Answer (score 3):

Try for of

check this snippet

```js
const arr =[{id: 4, imageIndex: 3}]
for (var item of arr) {
console.log(item.imageIndex);
}
```

Comment: imageList is not iterable is the error I receive when I use of instead